# How to disable Kaspersky repetitive null requests showing on Chrome's Network Developer Tool?

Tags: networking, security, anti-virus, kaspersky, google-chrome-devtools

Kaspersky creates repetitive requests appearing annoyingly on the ***Developer Tools > Network*** on any webpage I try to analyze. I'm looking for disabling Kasersky requests to appear at all. That is to keep the Network log clean and neat showing only requests made to the website I'm analyzing only.

---

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

---

**OS:** Windows 10, **Version of Kaspersky:** Total Security 16.x

Comment: The fourth icon on the Network toolbar should be 'Filter'.  It should be red if it is turned off, or blue if it is showing somewhere on screen already.  Have you already tried filtering with it?

Comment: @panhandel No I've not tried it. I think filtering needs prior knowledge of all addresses the website would request. My website runs remote scripts which I don't know what addresses it would request. I am looking for a way to neglect requests made by Kaspersky, or preferrably disable them from the beginning if this won't cause a security leakage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaspersky injects a script into web traffic for protection purposes. There's an option within [KIS](https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=344430) / [KTS](http://support.kaspersky.com/12185#block1) ([DL](http://products.kaspersky-labs.com/products/english/homeuser/kts5/kts16.0.1.445en-us_full.exe)) **16.01.445** to disable script injection. Just go to *Kaspersky Settings* > *Additional* > *Network* > *Traffic Processing* > ***uncheck Inject Script***.

Reference: [Answer on Kaspersky Forums](https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=350647&view=findpost&p=2586032)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue in 2023. A different solution is to exclude requests made to URLs containing the word "kaspersky":

1. In the **Filter** input field type **kaspersky**;
2. Check **Invert** next to it.

I prefer this method to avoid potentially limiting the protection.

Answer (score -1):

It's 2024 and Kasperksy is at version 21. Here's what you have to do to get rid of those requests:

- in Kaspersky search for "traffic"
- go to Network Settings
- uncheck "Inject script into web traffic to interact with web pages"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).